# Convergence of the sequence $a_n = \sqrt{n}$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I know that in general, a Cauchy sequence isn't necessarily a convergent sequence. However, if the space the sequence is in is complete, all Cauchy sequences will converge.

Now the sequence given exists in the real numbers which are complete.

It's easy to see that $a_n \to \infty$ when $n \to \infty$, so this sequence cannot be convergent. Yet we can check that $(a_{n+1} - a_n) \to 0$ which would mean that it should be Cauchy since this should imply that $ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N$ s.t. If $m,n >N$ then $a_m - a_n < \epsilon$.

So on one hand it diverges, while on the other it's Cauchy in a complete metric space giving us convergence. What am I missing?

Comment: $(a_{n+1} - a_n) \to 0$ doesn't imply that a sequence is Cauchy. $$a_m - a_n = \sum_{k = n}^{m-1} (a_{k+1} - a_k)$$ can still be large. Here, we have $\sqrt{(n+k)^2} - \sqrt{n^2} = k$ for example.

Comment: @Fischer   Oh I get it. My condition only guarantees the distance between consecutive terms goes to zero, which is a stronger condition than required by a Cauchy sequence..?

Comment: The other way round, Cauchy is the (much) stronger condition.

Comment: @DanielFischer   right, right, got my words mixed up... I see now why it is not Cauchy, but it still blows my mind that the sequence can blow up to infinity while consecutive terms keep getting closer. Would it be fair to say intuitively that this is so because the terms of the sequence *grow* to infinity faster than the difference of terms *shrinks* to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $a_n=\sqrt{n}$, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_{4n}-a_n)=$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}=+\infty.$$

thus, $(a_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence.